# Check if cell is empty or not

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm new to `excel` , I need to check if cell is empty put `zero` and if not don't change value

I tried to use  `=IF(" ",0,**)`

But instead of `**`  I don't know How can i make it don't change the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),0,A1)
```

the problem with your formula is that there is no cell reference. Here we are checking the cell A1 if it is empty or not.

**Update**

Since it seems that the cell are not actually blank, try to use this formulae

```
=IF(TRIM(A1)="",0,A1)
```

You can actually join the two formula

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),TRIM(A1)=""),0,A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please, `=IF(A1>0,A1,0)` Please note: this will work on a different column, not the same.